# apache spark yarn cluster

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a spark stand alone appliaction in **yarn-client** mode(with out spark-submit). I gave spark-assembly-1.1.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar and hadoop conf (yarn-site.xml) in the class path but yarn is not picking ResourceManager url from the yarn-site.xml instead it defaults to 8032 port.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you have added more than one path in your `classpath`, you have to make `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` **the first one**.

This is my application's boot script:

```
set HADOOP_CONF_DIR=D:\data\yarnv2_5\Hadoop\etc\hadoop
set PATH=%PATH%;D:\data\AppDependencies\jdk1.8\bin
set JAVA_HOME=D:\data\AppDependencies\jdk1.8
set AKKA_HOME=%~dp0
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx100g -Xms1024M -Xss1M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
set AKKA_CLASSPATH=%AKKA_HOME%\*

rem The order matters! Be sure to put HADOOP_CONF_DIR in the first place.
set APP_CLASSPATH = %HADOOP_CONF_DIR%;%AKKA_CLASSPATH%

java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp "%IN4_CLASSPATH%"  com.Application
```

If you pick more than one paths in `classpath`, Hadoop(or more precisely, JVM) will stop once it finds the config file. The first path tends to be your current path, where it will find the config file in your spark-assembly-1.x.x-hadoop-2.x.x.jar, and your config in HADOOP_CONF_DIR will show no effect.